# convert all lines in file to lowercase then write to new file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read in a file and convert its contents to lowercase then write it back out all lowercase in the same fashion / order ( one word per line and the lines are in alphabetical order ) to a new file.

Ultimately, what I am trying to do is to convert all the lines in this life to lowercase letters.

Why isn't this python script doing this and how can I do this in Python 2.7:

```
from itertools import chain
from glob import glob

lines = set(chain.from_iterable(open(f, 'rU') for f in glob('./files/*.txt')))

with open('listTogether.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in lines:
         line.lower()
    out.writelines(sorted(lines))
```

Comment: Python strings are *immutable*, so `line.lower` returns a new string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not replacing the `line.lower()` back into the list.

Try:

```
lines = [line.lower() for line in lines]
with open('listTogether.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.writelines(sorted(lines))
```